# Phonegap On Android 6 - How to get external storage path

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to get external storage path in Phonegap. I'm using this code but it never handles the correct SDCard path.

```
(function(){
    window.appRootDirName = ".myapp";
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory);
        console.log("device is ready");
        window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function fail() {
        console.log("failed to get filesystem");
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        console.log("filesystem got");
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory(window.appRootDirName, {
            create : true,
            exclusive : false
        }, dirReady, fail);
    }

    function dirReady(entry) {
        window.appRootDir = entry;
        alert(JSON.stringify(window.appRootDir));
    }
})();
```

also

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
```

and

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Emulated" />
```

doesn't help.

Are there a way to get the correct SDCard path on Android 6 with phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

This is how i made it work in android as well as in iOS,

```
function writeFile() {
            if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
            } else {
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
            }

        }    

        function onError(e) {
            alert("onError");
        };

        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            var entry = "";
            if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                entry = fileSystem;
            } else {
                entry = fileSystem.root;
            }
            entry.getDirectory("Folder_Name", {
                create: true,
                exclusive: false
            }, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
        };

        function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) {
            dir.getFile(filename, {
                create: true,
                exclusive: false
            }, gotFileEntry, errorHandler);
        };

        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            // logic to write file in respective directory
        };

        function errorHandler(e) {
            // handle error
        }
```

Comment: @fobus, Since you are testing in Android 6, folder creation may fail for you due to permission issue with cordova file plugin. You may have to pull the latest FileUtils.java from android src folder in file plugin github to make this work. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
}

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("App_files", {create: false, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectoryWin, onGetDirectoryFail);
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}

var onGetDirectoryWin = function(parent) {

}
var onGetDirectoryFail = function() {
    console.log("error getting dir")
}
```

Comment: No, It didn't worked for me, it is returning file:///data/user/0/com.myapp.music/files/files/